# Can print out an object, but cannot access its values in JS

Tags: javascript, json, request-promise

I know this will be a very stupid question, but I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. I'm getting the following response back from an API I'm using:

```
{
  "item_id": "51c3d78797c3e6d8d3b546cf",
  "item_name": "Cola, Cherry",
  "brand_id": "51db3801176fe9790a89ae0b",
  "brand_name": "Coke",
  "item_description": "Cherry",
  "updated_at": "2013-07-09T00:00:46.000Z",
  "nf_ingredient_statement": "Carbonated Water, High Fructose Corn Syrup and/or Sucrose, Caramel Color, Phosphoric Acid, Natural Flavors, Caffeine.",
  "nf_calories": 100,
  "nf_calories_from_fat": 0,
  "nf_total_fat": 0,
  "nf_saturated_fat": null,
  "nf_cholesterol": null,
  "nf_sodium": 25,
  "nf_total_carbohydrate": 28,
  "nf_dietary_fiber": null,
  "nf_sugars": 28,
  "nf_protein": 0,
  "nf_vitamin_a_dv": 0,
  "nf_vitamin_c_dv": 0,
  "nf_calcium_dv": 0,
  "nf_iron_dv": 0,
  "nf_servings_per_container": 6,
  "nf_serving_size_qty": 8,
  "nf_serving_size_unit": "fl oz",
}
```

And this is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

module.exports = {
 getIngredients: function(req, callback) {
 rp({
  method: 'GET',
  uri: `https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/item?upc=${req.body.upc}&appId=${process.env.NUTRITIONIX_APP_ID}&appKey=${process.env.NUTRITIONIX_APPP_KEY}`
 }).then((data) => {

  console.log(`Talked to NutritionixAPI, result was: ${data}`);
  var ingredients = data.nf_ingredient_statement.split(',');

  console.log(`Ingredients split from the data are: ${ingredients}`);

  return callback(ingredients);

  }).catch((err) => {
   console.log(`Error occured in NutritionixAPI, ${err}`)
   return callback(Object.assign({}, err, { error: true }));
  });
 }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is why `data` gets printed to the console properly, but as soon as I try to access any value inside, I get the error of it being `undefined`. I've tried other values in the JSON as well, so I would very much appreciate the help!

**EDIT:** I want to clarify what the question is about, it's not about the callback and async calls because those work perfectly. My issue is specifically with `var ingredients = data.nf_ingredient_statement.split(',');` where `nf_ingredient_statement` is undefined even though obviously it isn't.

Comment: Don't take a `callback`. `return` the promise!

Comment: @Bergi: callbacks "work" just fine. Maybe not preferred, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. The problem here is probably the `return` statement in `return callback(...)`

Comment: @Cerbrus The return statement works fine, because everything in the callback runs properly. The issue here is with `var ingredients = data.nf_ingredient_statement.split(',');` where `nf_ingredient_statement` is undefined.

Comment: @ScaVenGerS: is `data` a JSON string? (In that case: `data = JSON.parse(data)`)

Comment: What exactly would you mean by JSON string, the JSON above is exactly what gets printed to the console (with quotes around key and values). Let me try to parse it as JSON.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yup, it was a JSON string apparently, I knew the answer would be stupid simple. Thank you!

Comment: Then I'd close it as duplicate of: [Parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `data` is a JSON string so you can't access it before parsing it, that's why `data.nf_ingredient_statement` is `undefined`.

You need to parse `data` first, your code should be like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
var ingredients = json.nf_ingredient_statement.split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what I was getting back was a JSON string. So I just needed to do `data = JSON.parse(data)` to parse it into actual JSON.